# how to change send button color when I enter some text in my input tag in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

how to change send button colour when I enter some text in my input tag in angular 6?
In the image I have to change colour of send button when my text is entered in input text field

```html
      <div class="conversation">
        <input id="chatMessageBox" row="1" placeholder="continue typing.." autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"
          autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="text-input" [(ngModel)]="message"  (keydown)="sendMessageUsingKeypress($event)">
         
        <div class="send">
          <i class="material-icons" (click)="onSubmit(message)">
            send
          </i>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here i want to change color of send when i enter some text in inputbox

Comment: please share your HTML code that we better to know what you want to do so far

Comment: Added my requirement Can you please check Help me out If you are able to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way use angular style `[style.background-color]="message && message != '' ? 'red' : 'green'"  [style.color]="message && message != '' ? 'black' : 'white'"`

```
<div class="send" [style.background-color]="message && message != '' ? 'red' : 'green'"  [style.color]="message && message != '' ? 'black' : 'white'">
          <i class="material-icons" (click)="onSubmit(message)">
            send
          </i>
          <br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I am a  beginer

Answer (score 1):

Use NgClass

ex.

```
[ngClass]="{'color-1': message.length > 0, 'color-2': message.length === 0}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[style.color]="message.length > 0 ? 'white' : 'red'"
```